# Angular 5 - typesafe http.get request and other responsetypes than json?

Tags: request, angular5

I'm wondering, if it is possible to use another responseType than 'json' when performing a typesafe http request.

e.g. following line (this does not work!)

```
this.http.get<User>('myURL', { responseType: 'xml' as 'text' });
```

May somebody knows how to change the (JSON) parser behind the get method?

best regards, r.anwar